# Minecraft Server port opens but wont STAY open

Tags: port, forwarding, hosting, minecraft

I've been hosting a Minecraft (FTB Infinity Lite, to be precise) for some friends for about a week now.

My issue:

Port is forwarded, once server is started, players can join perfectly fine, all is well.

Port will close again at a random point of time.

Players who were in the server before the port closed stay in the server, but new players can't join.

Sometimes a player (who joined before the port closed) leaving can reopen the port (sometimes not).

Does anyone out there know the solution?

Comment: Static or dynamic IP address

Comment: static, of course